# Problem in Algorithm Code

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode, algorithmic

I am trying to complete my research paper in LaTeX but getting following three errors. I have tried so many things from the internet but to no advantage. Could any one help me please?

**1)**

> File ended while scanning use of \ELSIF.\par \input{proposed-scheme}

**2)**

> LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \begin{algorithm}[t]

**3)**

> LaTeX Error: Command \ALC@lno already defined.Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \begin{algorithmic}[1]

Error type 3 is coming many times.

Here is the working example of the algorithm.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{IEEEtran}    
\usepackage{algorithmic}    
\usepackage{algorithm}    

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}    
\caption{Abc..}    
\label{alg1}    
\begin{algorithmic}[1]    
\STATE Phase 1: Compute (abc)    
\STATE abc    
\FOR {condition}    
\STATE Compute abc   
\ENDFOR    

\STATE Phase 2: Optimization (xyz)    
\FOR {condition}
\STATE xyz        
\IF {condition}    
\STATE xyz        
\ELSIF {condition}    
\STATE xyz    
\ENDIF    
\ENDFOR    
\STATE return xyz to Algorithm 1    
\end{algorithmic}    
\end{algorithm}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example is neither compilable nor minimal. Please try to minimize that in order to give less work to us. Thanks.

Comment: You missed a \begin{document} right before \begin{algorithm}

Comment: @mani In order to help a bit on your MWE: The first 13 packages can be deleted without effecting the output (I guess... try that and trace down your problem). We do not have a package `mystyle` on our PCs. Do we need caption, label, fontsize, papersize in order to see your errors? Could you reproduce the same with a more standard documentclass like `article`. Do we really need to check 20 `\STATE`-commands in order to help or would 1 be enough. Please edit your question and a lot of people will be happy to help. Your MWE should still show the three errors, though.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Yes my document has footnote on first page. Please try the reduced example now.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I also have few other algorithms before this algorithm and all those algorithms compile properly, but this algorithm is causing trouble.

Comment: @mani Your code is not compilable as it is now missing a documentclass. But nevertheless, the example is useless as it produces no error at all. We can't correct your mistakes if we can't see them. If you can't compile the code, you have posted, you have to check if your system is up to date. But I guess your error is in one of the few other algorithms as this one prints just fine.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I tried compilation after removing one algorithm in each attempt, but problem still persists.

Comment: @mani Sorry, but you are really not helping us. You have not considered all points mentioned in my second comment and you are talking about several algorithms but showing just one which is completely fine. Please compile just the code you posted with PDFLaTeX. If this does not work come back to me. If it does, you will have to put some effort into producing an MWE which shows your three errors.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is resolved. Actually, I was missing one of the "}" characters, which I figured out. However, now I want to give separate line numbering to procedure 1 and procedure 2 within the same Algorithm. Could you please help me in that?

Answer (score 1):

The MWE is useless, because it does not generate any of the errors.

**Ad 1)** It seems, that the syntax in an environment `algorithmic` is not correct, probably an `\ENDIF` is missing.

**Ad 2)** Environment `algorithm` cannot be used in floats like `figure` or `table` because it is already a float object.

**Ad 3)** Usually `\ALC@no` is locally defined in the start code of `algorithmic` and the definition is dropped by `\end{algorithmic}`. Thus it could be caused by a missing `\end{algorithmic}` or it is a consecutive error of 1).

Comment: Ad 1) The conditional statement is one multi-condition statement, i.e., \IF - \ELSIF - \ELSIF - \ELSIF - \ELSIF - \ELSE - \ENDIF. So where is the syntax error.

Comment: @mani http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: I could not interpret Ad 2 and Ad 3 at all. Could you please elaborate upon them? What is \ALC@no. Sorry - but lack of my knowledge.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek I guess you are right on Ad 2 and may be on Ad 3 as well. How to avoid the Ad 2 error?

Comment: @mani Ad 2: There is no source or MWE. Check your `.log` file, where the error occurs (file, line number) and check, if the environment `algorithm` around this location or right before, whether it is wrapped inside another environment or macro.

Comment: @mani Ad 2: If there is indeed a wrapping `figure` or `table` environment, then move `algorithm` outside.